# What could be causing this "Fatal Exception: CALayerInvalidGeometry CALayer bounds contains NaN: [nan nan; nan nan]" crash?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have the following bit of code which simply initializes a `UIImageView` to fit a `UIImage` proportionally for as large as it possibly can be on the current screen dimension:

```
CGSize mainScreenSize = [appDelegate mainScreenSize];
CGSize superViewSize = CGSizeMake(mainScreenSize.width, mainScreenSize.height);
CGSize size = [self.image size];

CGFloat xScale = superViewSize.width / size.width;
CGFloat yScale = superViewSize.height / size.height;

CGFloat minimumScale = MIN(xScale, yScale);
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width * minimumScale, size.height * minimumScale)];

self.imageView.image = self.image;
self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width * minimumScale, size.height * minimumScale);

[self addSubview:self.imageView];
```

For some reason, when some of my users are using the app, the part of the code where the `frame` of the `UIImageView` is being set is leading to the following crash:

```
Fatal Exception: CALayerInvalidGeometry CALayer bounds contains NaN: [nan nan; nan nan]
```

In checking my crash logs, the error seems to be consistent across all iOS versions, devices, and orientations so I've ruled that out. As a side note, I use to implement the above code like this:

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageSize.width, self.imageSize.height);
[self addSubview:self.imageView];
```

And then after it attached itself to the superview, I would perform a transform on the UIImageView to resize it and I never received the above error (I had to change to the new method due to work around a bug caused by another framework).

I know the above error is usually caused by divide by 0 or setting the frame width and height to 0, but I'm just having a hard time figuring out how that's happening. I don't think the issue is with the imageSize, because as I said previously I never had an issue with that with the previous methodology. As for the mainScreen size, here is the method in my app delegate:

```
- (CGSize) mainScreenSize
{
    CGSize mainScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if ([OperatingSystemVersion operatingSystemVersionLessThan:@"8.0"] && UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
    {
        mainScreenSize = CGSizeMake(mainScreenSize.height, mainScreenSize.width);
    }

    return mainScreenSize;
}
```

Anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Actually realized that I was setting my image property like this in .h:

```
@interface DynamicImageView : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    UIImage *_image;
}
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
```

But I wasn't synthesizing it in my .m file. Could this have caused the problem? I'm wondering how this even works most of the time and only crashes sometimes?

Comment: Your error is caused, because you enter invalid numbers (NaN -"Not a Number"). I suppose that some of your objects are `nil` when you try to create the frames. Check that through logs and breakpoints.

Comment: @croX But when I used the old methodology, it never used to crash. I don't think the UIImage is nil.

Comment: @croX Maybe you're right actually, I edited my post to show how I was initializing my self.image property, and I was forgetting to synthesize it. I'm wondering how it even works at all because of that, or why only sometimes it's causing it to crash.

Comment: Maybe it is not necessarily the image. It also might be an error in your `[appDelegate mainScreenSize]` method. I don't know your code, but you are definitely having an invalid object somewhere, that causes your frame calculation to produce a invalid (NaN) number :)

Comment: The compiler automatically synthesizes your properties. So this should not be the error

Comment: @crox What if the code above was taking place in an init method, before synthesization, could that make a difference?

Comment: I think that wouldn't change anything either. But it is really hard for me to tell, as I don't know your entire code. It would be the best to check all involved parameters step by step.

Comment: @crox Alright will do. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is when users load in photos from their photo library, if there isn't enough memory to load the photo in, then `nil` will be returned for the `UIImage`. So my code above was trying to create an `UIImageView` with a `frame` based on the sized of a `nil` `UIImage` thus causing it to crash. I fixed this by handling the case when a `nil` `UIImage` is returned from my `UIImagePickerController`.